# How to display list of images in listview from database using android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

In my case i would be retrieving values from sqlite database and have to display it in a list view...So how should i pass the images out from the database into the list view.. I am able to save and retrieve images individually and display it on the screen.But how do i pass a bitmap and display it in a list view.can you help me with some sample codes please...

Answer (score 4):

Check this given below link

http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/listview-with-image-and-text-problem-t13694.html#p86517